# A specific piece of state does not update - React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, setstate, google-maps-react

I am using the Google Maps Javascript API  provided by Google Cloud platfform.
The Map Component has an attribute named **styles**. This attribute tells the map what it should be rendered, like restaurants, parks and more.

The problem is when I call the setState method and update what I want to show in map, differently of the others elements that I have on my state, nothing happens.

Look at one peace of the code to understand what I refering to:
*This is my method when I don't want to show the defaults **poi** features on the map*

```
        this.setState({
            showPoiFeatures: false,
            mapTypeStyle: [
                {
                    featureType: "poi",
                    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
                },
            ]
        })
    }
```

And this is the attribute that I talking above

```
<Map
    className="map"
    initialCenter={{ lat: -23.0916907, lng: -47.2216777 }}
    zoom={14}
    google={this.props.google}
    onClick={this.onClickMap}
    controlSize="1"
    clickableIcons={false}
    styles={this.state.mapTypeStyle}
>
```

Here is my initial state:

```
state = {
        variable1: {},
        variable2: {
            object: {
                variable3: '',
                variable4: 0,
                variable5: 0,
                variable6: 0,
                variable7: '',
                variable8: 0,
                variable9: '',
                variable10: 0,
                variable11: 0
            }
        },
        variable12: true,
        mapTypeStyle: [],
        showPoiFeatures: true,
    }
```

A empty array means that I want to show all features on the map

If this text got confused, please ask me to explain more. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the the correct title is: An specific piece of state is not updating

Comment: Hi its little confusing like, you are defining styles in state? and also, can you please post a little bit codes before the `this.setState` line. (you might want to change variable names if confidential things,

Comment: one quick resolution, i think, in `styles` in second block of code, it should be `{{ <code> }}` double brackets. can you please try once and confirm?

Comment: Could you please post a link to the API documentation. Also, are you sure that it's `styles` and not `styles`? Also should it take in an array or an object, because you are currently passing in an array.

Comment: @kishore, i tried to put double brackets, but not work

Comment: @MichaelM. Sorry, it's array of objects. The documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference

Comment: Could you please add your logic for updating the state?

Comment: @MichaelM. I have two radios buttons on the map, "Hide" and "Show" features. When user click "Hide", I call setState, set the "showPoiFeatures" to false and include the array on mapTypeStyle. 

And when user click "Show", I set the "showPoiFeatures" to true, and include an empty array to mapTypeStyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` parameter of the `<Map/>` takes CSS style object - commonly width and height. If you want the [custom map style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#custom-map-style) you need to use the `setOptions>styles`.
Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mapstyle-showhide-ehzqnh?file=Map.js) (N*ote: use an API key for the code to work properl*y) and a code snippet below on how to achieve this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

const mapStyle = [
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
  }
];

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      mapVariable: true
    };
  }
  _mapLoaded(mapProps, map) {
   
    this.setState({
      mapVariable: map
    });
  }

  showStyle = () => {
    this.state.mapVariable.setOptions({
      styles: mapStyle
    });
  };

  hideStyle = () => {
    this.state.mapVariable.setOptions({
      styles: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    const coords = { lat: 40.712775, lng: -74.005973 };
    const containerStyle = {
      position: "relative",
      width: "600px",
      height: "600px"
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="show"
            name="choice"
            value="show"
            onClick={this.showStyle}
          />
          <label for="show">Show</label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="hide"
            name="choice"
            value="hide"
            onClick={this.hideStyle}
          />
          <label for="hide">Hide</label>
          <br />
        </form>
        <Map
          containerStyle={containerStyle}
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={16}
          initialCenter={coords}
          onReady={(mapProps, map) => this._mapLoaded(mapProps, map)}
        >
          <Marker position={coords} />
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "YOUR_KEY"
})(MapContainer);
```